# Sencha touch toolbar, list and button in a tabPanel

Tags: javascript, layout, sencha-touch

I have a sencha touch app here: http://jsfiddle.net/sSyqF/ where I want the first tab in the tabPanel to have a toolbar docked at the top, a list in the middle, and the big button docked at the bottom. As you can see, it's not doing that. Any suggestions? I'm still new to Sencha Touch's layout system, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just open your example in the google chrome (sencha touch works only on webkit, not firefox), it seems to be what you want. Sencha has a very good documentation with videos, code library, and kitchen example. explore it.

Comment: @albanx in my google chrome (and safari, both latest versions), I do not see a big button with a + at the bottom above the tab panel, nor can I scroll down and see all the list items. I've scoured the documentation and forums for sencha touch, and can't find anything.

Comment: I hav had similar errors. In your case the button seems to be under the list so it is not visible. If you change to this items: [toolbar,bigButton, list] you will see that the buttons appear at the top. You should play around and find what option should be used for understandint what's the problem. I have had similar problems but I can't say how I resolved because I don't have the code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sSyqF/10/ is this the desired result or you want the button to be at the end of the list, i.e. to be like a list item?

Comment: Yes, perfect! The last list item or two seem to be hidden behind the tabPanel and button, though.

Comment: I was able to get it fixed (http://jsfiddle.net/9eqcd/35/) by removing the height: 100% in the javascript, and adding a bottom: 33px; value in the css for it. Thanks for your help!